# Convert MS-SQL Server stored procedure to MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am stuck at this for the past hour and unable to convert this MSSQL Server stored procedure to "MySQL query":

```
DECLARE @LedgerTbl TABLE (PARTY_ID VARCHAR(100),VRDATE VARCHAR(200),
                          VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),
                          DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL,
                          CREDIT DECIMAL, RunningTotal decimal) 

DECLARE @RunningTotal decimal 

SET @RunningTotal = 0 

INSERT INTO @LedgerTbl 
SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO VRNOA,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null 
FROM PLEDGER WHERE PARTY_ID=@partyId AND VRDATE BETWEEN @from AND @to 
ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,VRNOA 

UPDATE @LedgerTbl 
SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) 
FROM @LedgerTbl 

SELECT * FROM @LedgerTbl
```

How may I convert this to a single MySQL query or a MySQL Stored procedure?

**UPDATE**

I tried to transform it to but it is giving me these error that I have given below:

```
DELIMETER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;
    SET RunningTotal = 0;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LedgerTbl (PARTY_ID VARCHAR(100),VRDATE VARCHAR(200),VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL,RTotal decimal);
    INSERT INTO LedgerTbl 
    SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO VRNOA,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null 
    FROM PLEDGER WHERE PARTY_ID=17 AND VRDATE BETWEEN '2013/12/02' AND '2010/12/02' 
    ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,VRNOA; 

    UPDATE LedgerTbl 
    SET RunninTotal = RTotal = RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) 
    FROM LedgerTbl; 

    SELECT * FROM LedgerTbl;
END//
DELIMETER;
```

Here are the errors:

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

> ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 10 STR: // SQL: DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL;
>
> SQL query:
>
> DELIMETER// CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN DECLARE
>   RunningTotal DECIMAL;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMETER//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` () BEGIN
>       DECLARE RunningTotal' at line 1

Can anyone please review it?

Comment: If you mean, do the exact same thing in a single query, **you can't** as your procedure has insert and update operation. In fact, you cant do this in any RDBMS.

Comment: Just convert it to a MySQL stored procedure.

Comment: @JorgeCampos won't it be possible with sub queries. For the insert and update that you are saying, it doesn't actually insert and update. It is used here to populate the intermediate table `@ledgerTbl` just to achieve the purpose.

Comment: I don't have the time for doing a full port, sorry. Also, it would be good exercise for you (provided you're newbie). I would start with checking how variables are declared in a MySQL stored procedure (SP). The rest of the SP logic doesn't seem too complex to me.

Comment: Who is this two parameters: `@from AND @to`

Comment: These will be passed to the stored procedure while calling it.

Comment: @peter.petrov I have tried to write this stored procedure. Will you please check that. It's still giving me errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow isn't meant to be a code writing service.

Comment: add ; at the end of each statement

Comment: @JoeTaras Still it's still giving me this error. I have updated the question would you please check it.

Comment: @KamranAhmed: Change CREATE TEMPORARY LedgerTbl TABLE in CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LedgerTbl. There are some errors, correct those step by step ;)

Comment: @JoeTaras thanks for helping. I've changed that and now it's these errors again. I've updated the question. Will you please check them? Thanks :'-)

Comment: @KamranAhmed: In MySql not exists UPDATE ... FROM construct (I hate MySql), you can't update the same table presents in a subquery. When define you var add precision, i.e. DECIMAL(19,2).

Comment: @JoeTaras then how may I get this to work?

Comment: @KamranAhmed: Try with UPDATE JOIN or change approach. Can you write only using INSERT statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write this procedure on my own, here is the link that helped me understand the Stored Procedures in MySQL: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/. And the procedure that I came up wit

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Acc_Ledger`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE RunningTotal, deb, cred DECIMAL(19,2);
    DECLARE counter, row_count int;

    SET RunningTotal = 0;
    SET counter = 1;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LedgerTbl;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LedgerTbl (CTR int primary key auto_increment, PARTY_ID INT,VRDATE VARCHAR(200),VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL(19,2),CREDIT DECIMAL(19,2),RTotal DECIMAL(19,2));

    INSERT INTO LedgerTbl
    SELECT 0, PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null FROM PLEDGER WHERE PARTY_ID=17 AND VRDATE BETWEEN '2010/10/02' AND '2013/12/02' 
    ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,DCNO;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO row_count FROM LedgerTbl;

    WHILE counter <= row_count DO

        SELECT debit INTO deb FROM LedgerTbl WHERE ctr = counter;
        SELECT credit INTO cred FROM LedgerTbl WHERE ctr = counter;
        SET RunningTotal = RunningTotal + (deb-cred);

        UPDATE LedgerTbl 
        SET LedgerTbl.RTotal = RunningTotal
        WHERE ctr = counter;  

        SET counter = counter + 1;

    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM LedgerTbl;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

## UPDATE

Now I found the comparatively efficient solution:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Acc_Ledger`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE RunningTotal, deb, cred DECIMAL(19,2);
    DECLARE counter, row_count int;

    SET RunningTotal = 0;
    SET counter = 1;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LedgerTbl;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LedgerTbl (CTR int primary key auto_increment, PARTY_ID INT,VRDATE VARCHAR(200),VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL(19,2),CREDIT DECIMAL(19,2),RTotal DECIMAL(19,2));

    INSERT INTO LedgerTbl
    SELECT 0, PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null FROM PLEDGER WHERE PARTY_ID=17 AND VRDATE BETWEEN '2010/10/02' AND '2013/12/02' 
    ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,DCNO;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO row_count FROM LedgerTbl;

    SET @RunningTotal := 0;

    UPDATE LedgerTbl 
    SET RTotal = (@RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + (DEBIT - CREDIT));

    SELECT * FROM LedgerTbl;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the MSSQL procedure calculates a running total,
I've tested this procedure (slighly modified) on sqlfiddle and it gives the following results:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e909/1

The MSSQL procedure contains probably a typo here: `SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO VRNOA,ETYPE,` it's not clear whether `DCNO VRNOA` are two separate columns, or maybe one column `DCNO_VRNOA` with "missing" underscore between them.
I assume that they are two separate columns.

To calculate a running total in MySql there is no need to use a temporary table.
This simple query does this task:

```
SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO, VRNOA,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,
       DEBIT,
       CREDIT, 
       @RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) RunningTotal 
FROM PLEDGER ,
     ( SELECT @RunningTotal:=0) init_variables
WHERE PARTY_ID=1 
  AND VRDATE BETWEEN '2013-11-11' AND '2013-11-11'
ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,VRNOA;
```

See demo here: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daa6e/1

The procedure might look like:

```
DELIMITER /
CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` ()
BEGIN
    SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO, VRNOA,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,
           DEBIT,
           CREDIT, 
           @RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) RunningTotal 
    FROM PLEDGER ,
         ( SELECT @RunningTotal:=0) init_variables
    WHERE PARTY_ID=1 
      AND VRDATE BETWEEN '2013-11-11' AND '2013-11-11'
    ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,VRNOA; 
END /
DELIMITER ;
```