# StoredprocedureinMSSQLtoMySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MSSQl, i would like to write it int My sql,
Any help or sugegstions please.I can not get to use XML function in Mysql.

stored proc:

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE uspGetProductDetailsCSV (
            @sku NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )
        AS
        BEGIN
            -

            SELECT T.C.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [SKU]
            INTO #tblPersons
            FROM (SELECT CAST ('<Name>' + REPLACE     (@sku, ',', '</Name><Name>') 
            + '</Name>' AS XML) AS [Products]) AS A
            CROSS APPLY Products.nodes('/Name') as T(C)

            SELECT *
            FROM ProductInformation Pr
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM #tblPersons tmp WHERE tmp.SKU  
                           = case when len(tmp.SKU) = 11 then Product_No+Colour_Code+Size_Code
                                  when len(tmp.SKU) = 8 then Product_No+Colour_Code
                                  when len(tmp.sku) = 6 then Product_No end)



            DROP TABLE #tblPersons
        END
```

**Edit: I could not write XML part of stored proc, as i have pasted same code in Mysql, it doesnt create stored proc**

**Error: >can not cast as XML<**

Comment: I would appreciate negative markers come up boldly and explain why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329643/convert-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-to-mysql-query

Comment: Show some effort. stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @Bleach thanks for this, i have made an effort to write this, but struck in capturing results into temp table and XMl statement as i have mentioned in the post

Comment: I did not downvote but I will attempt to explain why they did.  You are pasting code from one language and asking how to convert to another language without showing that you have made any attempt to do on your own.

Comment: I would show exactly what you have tried and the exact place where you are getting stuck.  Show your MySQL stored proc.

Comment: @Bleach Appreciate your comments. I could not even write XML part of code as i have explained in post

Comment: atleastputsomespacesbetweenwordsinaquestion

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar you mean atleast put name spaces :)

Comment: have you tried creating temp table in Mysql, @Ganesh_Devlekar you don't make any sense. OP has admitted he could not parse XML part. If you are able to help , you can.

Comment: Copy pasting a stored proc from one sql product to another is not a serious attempt at migrating a stored proc. All sql products have their own syntax. You have to do proper conversion manually.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe XML is a valid type in MySql.  Try just leaving it as a VARCHAR.

So, just remove the cast...I also think you will have to use CONCAT instead of + and change the [] around columns to ticks.

So Instead of:

```
FROM (SELECT CAST ('<Name>' + REPLACE     (@sku, ',', '</Name><Name>') 
+ '</Name>' AS XML) AS [Products]) AS A
```

TRY:

```
FROM (SELECT CONCAT('<Name>' , REPLACE(@sku, ',', '</Name><Name>'), 
'</Name>') AS `Products`) AS A
```